# Why does FaunaDB output differ from Graphqli?

Tags: graphql, faunadb

I have created a simple *user.gql* file

```
type Query {
users: [user]
userById(id:ID!):user
}

type user {
id: ID!
chat_data: String
}
```

My data is

```
 [
    {
        "id": "0815960b-9725-48d5-b326-7718c4749cf5",
        "chat_data": ""
    }
]
```

When I run this on my local server and use the query

```
{users{id}}
```

I see the expected output

```
{
"data": {
    "users": [
    {
        "id": "0815960b-9725-48d5-b326-7718c4749cf5"
    }
    ]
}
}
```

I have created a *user* collection on FaunaDB with the data

```
{
    "ref": Ref(Collection("user"), "324407037973758152"),
    "ts": 1645691670220000,
    "data": {
        "id": "0815960b-9725-48d5-b326-7718c4749cf5",
        "chat_data": ""
    }
}
```

and uploaded my *user.gql*, but when I run the GraphQl query

```
{users{id}}
```

I get the error

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
        "message": "Cannot query field 'id' on type 'userPage'. (line 3, column 5):\n    id\n    ^",
        "locations": [
            {
            "line": 3,
            "column": 5
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very unintuitive, but Fauna seems to be returning a paginated result. Read more about it [here](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/graphql/pagination).

The best thing would be to GraphiQL to have a look at the schema of the Fauna GraphQL endpoint. Autocomplete should also work when you look for fields to query. The error basically says that you can't query the id directly. Try this:

```
{ users { data { id } } }
```

Comment: This, of course, doesn't work on the local server.Am I bound to treat development/test different from production?

Comment: FaunaDB has a Docker container that you can use to run a database locally. It is also super cheap and easy to set up databases, so you could just create one or multiple databases for each developer. If you want to hear my two cents, I am not a big fan of autogenerated GraphQL APIs over databases. Fauna is cool, but also has a steep learning curve. The closed sourceness makes it hard to play around with it locally.